# Binary search tree IEnumerator.MoveNext() non recursive in order traversal implementation. How to?

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree, ienumerable, enumerator

After having built a binary search tree `BST<Tkey,TValue>` which consists of `BSTNode<Tkey,TValue>` nodes I am trying to implement the IEnumerable interface for it.

This is the how I construct the `BSTNodeEnumrator<Tkey,TValue>`:

```
public class BSTNodeEnumerator<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerator<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    private Stack<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>> _stack;

    public BSTNodeEnumerator(BSTNode<TKey, TValue> root)
    {
        _stack = new Stack<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>>();
        _current = null;
        _root = root;
    }

    // ... rest of the implementation
}
```

I pass in `root` node and `_current` is the result of the enumeration. I am also trying to use a stack for this as I do not keep track of the parent node as in AVL BST.

Now I want the enumerator to traverse the tree in order + in a non recursive manner. That should result in a sorted enumeration as well due to the properties of a bst, which is great as that's exactly what I want to achieve.

The non-recursive algorithm for in order traversal in pseudo-code as in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

```
    iterativeInorder(node)
  s ← empty stack
  while (not s.isEmpty() or node ≠ null)
    if (node ≠ null)
      s.push(node)
      node ← node.left
    else
      node ← s.pop()
      visit(node)
      node ← node.right
```

We can transform the algorithm into this c# code:

```
public BSTNode<Tkey,TValue> Next() 
{
   while (_stack.Count > 0 || _current != null) 
    {
         if (_current != null)
         {
          _stack.Push(_current);
          _current = _current.left;
         }
         else
         {
          _current = _stack.Pop();
          BSTNode<Tkey,TValue> result = _current;
          _current = _current.Right;
         }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But that is not the required `bool MoveNext()` implementation as I have to return a bool. True if I did set `_current` to an appropriate node, false if I am at the end.

How should I go about implementing `public bool MoveNext()` ? The main thing that I can't wrap my head around is that If I want to transform `BSTNode<Tkey,TValue> Next()` into `bool MoveNext()` I have to `return true` instead of simply visiting the node `BSTNode<Tkey,TValue> result = _current;` and only after that set `_current = _current.Right;` which I obviously can't do.

Comment: Why not just use HashSet or Dictionary?

Comment: Do you need to make your own IEnumerator? why not just have your GetEnumerator function just return your implmentation but do a `yield return _current;` on the `BSTNode<Tkey,TValue> result = _current;` line. I will post a implmentation as an answer.

Comment: @MatthewWhited -  For sure I could simply use what is already in .Net, I am simply trying to learn. I am also fighting with AVL binary trees and skiplists as of now just for the sake of it. I am sure that's understandable. I mean .Net didn't just come from the sky.

Comment: Read the @ScottChamberlain comment. Iterator methods and `yield` statements are specifically made for non trivial enumerators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller is looping over the enumeration (probably in a foreach-loop). Therefore you can abort your loop each time you want to return a result. A problem arises, because `_current = _current.Right;` must be executed after the result has been determined. Therefore I am introducing a new variable `_result`.

```
private BSTNode<TKey, TValue> _result;

bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
{
    while (_stack.Count > 0 || _current != null)
    {
        if (_current != null)
        {
            _stack.Push(_current);
            _current = _current.left;
        }
        else
        {
            _current = _stack.Pop();
            _result = _current;
            _current = _current.Right;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

BSTNode<TKey, TValue> IEnumerator<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>>.Current
{
    get { return _result; }
}
```

Note that looping over an enumeration consists of first calling `MoveNext()` and testing the Boolean result. Then using the value returned by `Current` if `true` was returned.

Comment: Ah, thats the way to do it. I was trying to figure out the long way, I did not think of adding a result variable.

Comment: Maybe `_current` should better be named `_cursor` or `_temp` or something and `_result` should be turned into `_current`, because it is the backing field of the property `Current`.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, for a non trival enumerator like this it is better to just use the tools built in to .NET. It can automaticly convert the code you wrote in to a enumerator with only very minor tweaks by just returning `IEnumerator<BSTNode<Tkey,TValue>>` and using the `yield return` keyword.

```
class BSTNode<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>>
     where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    public IEnumerator<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>>();
        var current = this;
        while (stack.Count > 0 || current != null)
        {
            if (current != null)
            {
                stack.Push(current);
                current = current.Left;
            }
            else
            {
                current = stack.Pop();
                yield return current;
                current = current.Right;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public BSTNode<TKey, TValue> Left { get; set; }

    public BSTNode<TKey, TValue> Right { get; set; }

    public TKey Key { get; set; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

If you are curious, here is the compiler generated code for the IEnumerator class it made behind the scenes

```
[CompilerGenerated]
  private sealed class <GetEnumerator>d__0 : IEnumerator<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
  {
    private int <>1__state;
    private BSTNode<TKey, TValue> <>2__current;
    public BSTNode<TKey, TValue> <>4__this;
    private Stack<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>> <stack>5__1;
    private BSTNode<TKey, TValue> <current>5__2;

    BSTNode<TKey, TValue> IEnumerator<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>>.Current
    {
      [DebuggerHidden] get
      {
        return this.<>2__current;
      }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
      [DebuggerHidden] get
      {
        return (object) this.<>2__current;
      }
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <GetEnumerator>d__0(int <>1__state)
    {
      base.\u002Ector();
      this.<>1__state = param0;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
    }

    bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
    {
      switch (this.<>1__state)
      {
        case 0:
          this.<>1__state = -1;
          this.<stack>5__1 = new Stack<BSTNode<TKey, TValue>>();
          this.<current>5__2 = (BSTNode<TKey, TValue>) null;
          goto label_8;
        case 1:
          this.<>1__state = -1;
          this.<current>5__2 = this.<current>5__2.Right;
          break;
        default:
          return false;
      }
label_7:
label_8:
      if (this.<stack>5__1.Count <= 0 && this.<current>5__2 == null)
        return false;
      if (this.<current>5__2 != null)
      {
        this.<stack>5__1.Push(this.<current>5__2);
        this.<current>5__2 = this.<current>5__2.Left;
        goto label_7;
      }
      else
      {
        this.<current>5__2 = this.<stack>5__1.Pop();
        this.<>2__current = this.<current>5__2;
        this.<>1__state = 1;
        return true;
      }
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IEnumerator.Reset()
    {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I see, `yield return` basically retains the current state of the enumeration, making my life much easier.

Comment: @pijemcolu [here is the msdn page for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) if you would like to learn more. Other cool tricks you can do with `yield`, if you have a `try/finally` in your code, if the caller disposes of the `IEnumerator<T>` the code in the `finally` block will get executed if it was waiting on a `yield return` inside the `try` block.